# Accessing Time Machine for different computer

Tags: time-machine

My hard drive died on Computer 1.  Backed up to Time Machine.  Am now using Computer 2.
I need some files from the desktop of Computer 1.  Can I access them on Time Machine? How?
I have three computers all backing up to that time machine, but all I can see is the backups for Computer 2.  How do I find Computer 1?

Answer (score 9):

If you press the <kbd>option</kbd> key when clicking the time machine icon in the menu bar, you can browse backups from other computers.

[image]