# Can I connect external hardrive with time machine to someone else's mac to access one file

Tags: time-machine

Can I connect an external hardrive with time machine to someone else's mac and then access one file on time machine?

Comment: Piece of cake. TM is only a folder on the drive, for the most part, if it isn't encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. A Time Machine Backup is readable by any other Mac as long as the Time Machine Backup is not encrytped. Even then you can unlock it with your password.

Also see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139215/accessing-time-machine-for-different-computer?rq=1) answer.